# How to eliminate for-loop and use list comprehension when using numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, list-comprehension

I am trying to avoid using for-loop with numpy array.

If I have a code that looks like below:

```
psimaps = [np.zeros((10,10)) for i in range(len(features)-1)]

for k in range(len(features)-1):
    if k != len(features)-2:
        psimaps[k] = np.reshape(np.sum(featureParams*features[k], axis=1), (10,1)) + transitiveParams
    else:
        psimaps[k] = np.reshape(np.sum(featureParams*features[k], axis=1), (10,1)) + (np.sum(featureParams * features[k+1], axis=1)) + transitiveParams
return psimaps
```

How do I change this into a list representation to do this operation without a for loop? Thanks.

---

I added an original code. Basically, I'm generating new array computing from two arrays.

Comment: Your current code is basically equivalent to `10 * [featureParams + transitiveParams]`.  You'll need to give a bit more context.  Currently, you're making a bunch of numpy arrays and then discarding them.  What are you doing in a broader context?

Comment: More information is needed here. What are `featureParams` and `transitiveParams`?

Comment: @Joe, info looks complete to me, if you make some assumptions about shapes of the arrays.

Comment: @askewchan - It is now. The OP's edit added a lot of information!

Comment: @Joe, oh hadn't noticed the timing and wasn't sure what I was missing.  Sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically all you need to do is broadcast your `features` array to your `Params` arrays.  This can be done by inserting two new axes at the end of `features` (or more, if the `Params` arrays are not 2d).  Note that I used `keepdims` instead of the reshaping after the sum.

```
psimaps = np.sum(featureParams*features[..., None, None], axis=2, keepdims=True) + transitiveParams
```

After you do the above, you have to add the last two rows together, then remove the last row, since you had that strange end of loop thing:

```
psimaps[-2] += psimaps[-1] - transitiveParams
psimaps = psimaps[:-1]
```

By the way, I first had to simplify your original loop before I could understand it. I'll leave my simplified version here for any interest:

Fake data (and my assumption of shapes)

```
size = 30
features = np.random.rand(50)
transitiveParams = np.random.rand(size, size)
featureParams = np.random.rand(size, size)
```

Original code by OP

```
psimaps_OP = [np.zeros((size,size)) for i in range(len(features)-1)]
for k in range(len(features)-1):
    if k != len(features)-2:
        psimaps_OP[k] = np.reshape(np.sum(featureParams*features[k], axis=1), (size,1)) + transitiveParams
    else:
        psimaps_OP[k] = np.reshape(np.sum(featureParams*features[k], axis=1), (size,1)) + (np.sum(featureParams * features[k+1], axis=1)) + transitiveParams
```

simplified:

```
psimaps_simp = np.zeros((len(features)-1, size, size))
for k in range(len(features)-1):
    psimaps_simp[k] = np.sum(featureParams*features[k], axis=1, keepdims=True) + transitiveParams
psimaps_simp[-1] += np.sum(featureParams*features[-1], axis=1)
```

list comp:

```
psimaps_comp = [np.sum(featureParams*features[k], axis=1, keepdims=True) + transitiveParams for k in xrange(len(features)-1)]
psimaps_comp[-1] += np.sum(featureParams*features[-1], axis=1)
```

vectorised:

```
psimaps_vec = np.sum(featureParams*features[..., None, None], axis=2, keepdims=True) + transitiveParams
psimaps_vec[-2] += psimaps_vec[-1] - transitiveParams
psimaps_vec = psimaps_vec[:-1]
```

Next, check to make sure they all give the same result:

```
assert np.allclose(psimaps_simp, psimaps_OP), "simplification failed"
assert np.allclose(psimaps_simp, psimaps_vec), "vectorization failed"
```

Finally, timings:

```
#OP
100 loops, best of 3: 1.99 ms per loop

#simplified:
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.94 ms per loop

#list comp:
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.63 ms per loop

#vectorised:
1000 loops, best of 3: 407 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

If initialization is not important, maybe you can do like that:

```
psimaps = [ featureParams + transitiveParams for k in xrange(1,10)]
```

For each k, the sum featureParams + transitiveParams will be executed.